# Unique Path lifting of covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a covering map  (in particular $p$ is a fiber bundle with discrete fiber). We want to prove the following: Given a commuting diagram of the following form:

$\{0\}\rightarrow E$

$\downarrow\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \downarrow$

$I\ \ \rightarrow\ B$

Then there is a **unique** map $h:I\rightarrow E$, such that the upper and lower triangle commute.

What i have done so far: The existence of the map $h:I\rightarrow E$ is not the problem, since $p$ is a fiber bundle, hence a Serre fibration, hence we have the left lifting property with respect to all inclusions $I^n\times\{0\}\rightarrow I^n\times I$ for all $n\geq0$ by chosing $n=0$ we get our map $h:I\rightarrow E$. For the unqiueness i have problems. Suppose also $k:I\rightarrow E$ does the job. We want to prove that $h(t)=k(t)$ for all $t\in I$. But I only know that $k$ is such a digonal filler. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose you know that $h(0)=k(0)$. Let $y\in [0,1]$ be the supremum of $\{x:\,i(x)=k(x)\}$. By continuity of $i,k$ we have that $i(x)=k(x)$. Can you use the property that $p$ is a covering map to show that $y=1$?

Comment: Forget the diagrams and think about it: since you have already lifted $0$, you select an evenly covered neighborhood of $0$ and your lifting there is unique given that your lifting of $0$ chooses your component. So now you have lifted a "first portion" of the path. Now choose some $\epsilon > 0$ that you have lifted already; select an evenly covered neighborhood of it and you have your (unique) lifting again. Now keep doing this until you have filled the entire interval (connectedness argument).